# Why Atomic versions are missing for some primitive types while being present for some?

Tags: java, atomic, java.util.concurrent, compare-and-swap

Java provides  `AtomicInteger`,`AtomicLong` etc which basically compiles to  `CAS` instructions at hardware level. But why such AtomicXXX classes do not exist for other primitive types like `short` and floating point numbers like `float` and `double`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't CAS on less than a word. AtomicBoolean is implemented using an `int` and `float` could be implemented using an `int` and `double` using a `long`.

AFAIK, these were added as part of Doug Lea's  concurrency library being included and there hadn't been enough of a need to have Atmoic versions of these types before.

IMHO an AtomicDouble could be useful, but I avoid using `float` whenever possible due to the lack of precision.

Comment: There's an `AtomicDouble` in Guava.

Comment: @geek the hardware doesn't support it as a single operation. It could be implement but an AtomicShort would be a AtomicInteger with a cast.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Are you saying that exist in standard java libraries now ?Can you elaborate a little bit on "AFAIK, these were added as part of Doug Lea's concurrency library being included and there hadn't been enough of a need to have Atmoic versions of these types before."

Comment: Doug Lea's libraries were the basis for the concurrency library in Java 5.0, while classes have been added, there hasn't been an AtomicDouble added.  You can use an AtomicInteger to store a byte, short, or char.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many primitive types:)

If Java support generics for primitive types, we could have `Atomic<short>` etc. for all primitive types.

Without that, we have to declare AtomicXxx for each Xxx primitive type. API designers may find that unappealing.

The same thing happens in Java8. We have a generic `Function<A,B>`. But for performance reasons we would like to have primitive versions of `Function`, so we have `IntFunction` which is kind of `Function<int,B>`. But that is only done for `int, long, double`. There are no `ShortFunction` etc. They got too many "primitivized" types [1] and they are sick of it, so they stopped at these 3 types.

[1] http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html

See also Brian's answer : http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-March/008535.html

Comment: The "too many primitive types" reason doesn't make much sense. And the "if it was defined for all primitive types, it would have to be generic" thing makes even less sense in this particular case.

Comment: if there is only one primitive type left, e.g. `short`, that does not have a corresponding `AtomicXxx` class, you bet they'll add an `AtomicShort` just to be complete. But there are too many primitive types:)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to cap an AtomicInteger to a value. Let's say you want that to be a short. You can wrap the AtomicInteger into your custom type and use the modulo operation to cap the value. After reaching the max value, the value is recycled in the same manner when it would have hit the Integer.MAX value in the original AtomicInteger implementation.

```
public class AtomicShort
{
  private AtomicInteger root = new AtomicInteger();

  public short incrementAndGet()
  {
    return (short) (root.incrementAndGet() % Short.MAX);
  }
}
```

Comment: incrementAndGet()  is no more atomic in this case.